# What is the best way to upload files/images in the database using NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, database, api, file, server

What should i use to store the database as well as to upload the files/images to the server? Which should be the best and the easiest way to do this using Nodejs?

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: i used mongodb to save the data into the mongodb as text not for files/images

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's working for me so far.

1. convert the file to base64string sent to the server. This way you can send the request as application/json.
2. In the server convert the base64string to file. then save the file to your storage.
3. In the database, you just save the file path where you saved the file

Here's a simple code of my app. using S3 storage

```
 async uploadFile({ params }) {
    const {
      node, id, base64string, filename, type
    } = params
    const file_path = path.join(node, id, type, filename)
    await uploadToS3(
      Buffer.from(base64string.split(';').pop().replace('base64,', ''), 'base64'),
      file_path
    )
    return this.DB.updateById(
      node,
      { id, [type]: filename }
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another good option is azure blob storage. See the link for documentation on implementing with NodeJS. I have used this effectively to store base64 images.

[Azure Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-nodejs-v10)